# iCarouselTypeRotary iOS scrolling issue

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, icarousel

I have used iCarouselTypeRotary for some scrolling effect in my app, but currently the scrolling is enabled with only the view which is in front (selected), I want the scroll to be enable within the whole view.

Can anyone suggest me how to achieve this?

I have used the caraousel from here. https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Which one is your iCarousel view (which is in front)?

Comment: I have placed images in it. now the issue is the image which is in front, it contains only scrolling, I can not scroll from other portions (Left or Right) of the view. I want the scrolling to be occur in whole view, instead of the only one image. How can i achieve full scrolling area in it?

Comment: I did it by increasing the frame of the iCarousel in the view, where i added it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kindly make the iCarousel frame as self.view.frame 
This way you can use the iCarousel to the fullest of its capability.

However you can decrease the size according to your needs. Also change the backgroundcolor of iCarousel, so that you can see the frame size & adjust it to needs.

Comment: Thanks @Balram, I did it by increasing the frame of iCarousel as the view frame before your answer. +1 to your answer.

Comment: Kindly look at the iPhone & iPad Version of [this app](https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/pincode-search/id693049564?mt=8) & then you can get an idea of how I have done it there.